# Postgresql: currval() does not have any value if we dont run nextval() in the same session (Not in same trasaction)

Tags: postgresql, nativequery

Are there any alternatives to get currval() that is thread-safe.
JPA locking to generate thread-safe-sequence does the job but I am looking for a solution using NativeQuery.

Answer (score 0):

That is working as designed, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html):

> Returns the value most recently obtained by `nextval` for this sequence in the current session.

I don't see how that wouldn't be thread-safe. You can always see the current sequence value with

```
SELECT last_value FROM my_seq;
```

But that is of questionable value, because this value might already be outdated by the time you get the query result.